# Is there a Continuum in-universe source given for where Alec Sadler gets money for all his equipment?

Tags: continuum

In the show *Continuum*, the young Alec Sadler seems to have an amazing amount of technology available.  **Is there a canon/in-universe source listed for where he gets money for all those items?**   Even if Alec had obtained money to simply buy all the equipment, the power and bandwith requirements to maintain and operate it would seem to be very expensive.

His stepfamily and mom don't seem to be all that wealthy.  In particular, his step-father and step-brother and their activities seem to be "at odds" with what they consider to be the "wealthy elite".   This would imply they don't exactly have extra money lying around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the Syfy.com cast entry for Alec Sadler](http://www.syfy.com/continuum/cast/alec_sadler):

> A wiry, good looking teenager, Alec is intelligent but has always been
>   a bit of an outsider. Like Kiera (who uses his tech expertise as she
>   tries to track down the time travelling terrorists, LIBER8), he's
>   always moved to the beat of his own drummer. **His father was a genius
>   who made a lot of money creating all manner of technology.**
>
> It wasn't until his dad passed away that Alec, feeling grief-stricken
>   and abandoned, opened up his father's old workshop. Looking through
>   his father's diagrams and devices, he slowly began to realize he may
>   have a greater destiny.

**Emphasis added**

No doubt they mean his biological father.

Comment: It goes on to say that Alec's father is dead, without details. Did he die mysteriously? Or did he simply disappear into a blue police box?

Comment: Thanks PapaCharlie9.   It is interesting how much he (actually his mom if he is a minor) inherited then.  In addition to the workshop, he must have enough money to purchase all the ongoing power and bandwith.  Seems a bit at odds with the lifestyle they display.

Comment: @beichst I have a lamp with 2 [CFL bulbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp) that together draw 3x the power my laptop does.  It's kind of surprising what draws how much once you actually start measuring it.

Comment: So that just leaves power and bandwidth expenses.  For a hacker of Alec's caliber, those wouldn't be barriers.  I know he is presented as being generally honest (at least in Season 1; all I've watched so far), but seriously: does anyone think he's paying for all that satellite access?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Kellog splits from Liber8 in season one and starts investing and gambling, making millions with knowledge of future events, of course.  He then signs an agreement to give Alec all the resources / money he'll need.  I guess if you're talking about Alec's barn lab, pre-Kellog partnership, then we could assume that a lot of it was his biological father's, as previously mentioned.